# multiple conditions with if else

Tags: c#, .net

```
var car = repository.Get(id);
if(car != null)
{
  if(car.AdditionalInfo != null)
  {
     if(car.AdditionalInfo.CarOwner.Status == "USA")
     {
        ...
     }
     else
     {
       .. do something for
     }
  }
  else
  {
     // create additional info and save
  }
}
else
{

}
```

Having following situation in mind with multiple if conditions, is there some cleaner way to write this?
Don't focus on the Status property, rather to the flow of if else.

Comment: Use `switch` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) `?.`

```cs
if (car?.AdditionalInfo?.CarOwner?.Status == "USA")
{
...
}
```

If `car`, or `AdditionalInfo`, or `CarOwner` are null, then everything on the left will resolve to `null`, otherwise you will get the status, and then you can make your comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `?` operator:

```
var car = repository.Get(id);
if(car?.AdditionalInfo?.CarOwner?.Status == "USA" != null)
{
  
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: the `!= null` isnt needed

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to reduce nesting by inverting `if`s and introducing a function.
Null coalescing operator is obfuscating readability when there are several conditions. I would go with something alike, because here you only consider one condition at time:

```
public void HandleCar()
    {
        var car = repository.Get(id);
        
        if (car is null)
            return;

        if (car.AdditionalInfo is null)
        {
            // create additional info and save
            return;
        }

        if (car.AdditionalInfo.CarOwner.Status == "USA")
        {
            // ...
            return;
        }

        // .. do something for
    }
```